# Dynamic search function Photo album

Tags: laravel, searchable

I am trying to create a dynamic serch function to my PhotoAlbumn project. So I have installed Nicolaslopezj Searchable. However it does not work propertly as yet.

**Error**

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException
>   Call to undefined relationship [albums] on model [App\Photo]

Model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Nicolaslopezj\Searchable\SearchableTrait;

class Photo extends Model{
    use SearchableTrait;

    protected $searchable = [
    /**
     * Columns and their priority in search results.
     * Columns with higher values are more important.
     * Columns with equal values have equal importance.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    'columns' => [
        'albums.name' => 10,
        'photos.title' => 10,
        'photos.info' => 10,
        'albums.title' => 5,
      ],

    'joins' => [
        'albums' => ['photos.id','albums.id'],
    ],
];


  protected $fillable = array('photo','title','info','album_id');

  public function album(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Album');
  }
```

PhotoController

```
public function search(Request  $request){
    $query = $request->input('query');
    $result = Photo::search($query)
                    ->with('albums')  
                    ->get();

    return view('search.results')->with('result', $result);

  }
```

This relationship worked prior to using Nicolaslopezj Searchable.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `s` in your relationship.

Replace

```
    $result = Photo::search($query)
                    ->with('albums')  
                    ->get();
```

by

```
    $result = Photo::search($query)
                    ->with('album')  
                    ->get();
```

Comment: albums is the name of the table I am trying to join. If I change that I get an error

Comment: `with('albums')` calls the relation `albums()` that doesn't exist. What error do you get?

Comment: I get this error. Call to undefined relationship. albums() exists it in AlbumsController. Prior to using Nicolaslopezj Searchable. This worked, I joined albums in the PhotoController

Comment: Hello please remember that calling `with()` is calling a relationship NOT a join. Please remove the `s` and share the code in your question - not a comment